# how to get row that have number of digit more than two?

Tags: python

i want to normalize data that have number of digit more than two in my dataset.

I have been tried to use data[feature].astype(str).str.len() > 2 but unsolved.

```py
def normalisasi(data):
    column = list(data)
    for i in column:
        data[a]= data[i].astype(str).str.len()
        if data[a] == 5:
            data[i] = stat.zscore(data[i], axis=1, ddof=1)
        else:
            data[i] = data[i]
    return data
```

I expect to get the result that rows contain the number of digits more than 2 or equal, I can normalize it.

sample my dataset:

access  accommodates    amenities   availability_30
  0.0           2.0          1.0           25.0

my expected result value from availability will normalize using function normalization, that is the row that has digit number more than 10.00.

Comment: Can you add some input data and outputs for the same?

Comment: my sample data :                                                                                                                     access  | accommodates | amenities  | availability_30                                                                   
    0.0    |                2.0      |            1.0 |         25.0